# OutOfMemoryError when trying to read/write from a huge text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to read/write a huge text file.
But when I try to do that I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at ReadWriteTextFile.getContents(ReadWriteTextFile.java:52)
    at ReadWriteTextFile.main(ReadWriteTextFile.java:148)
```

My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadWriteTextFile {

  /**
  * Fetch the entire contents of a text file, and return it in a String.
  * This style of implementation does not throw Exceptions to the caller.
  *
  * @param aFile is a file which already exists and can be read.
  */    
  static public String getContents(File aFile) {
    //...checks on aFile are elided
      StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder(); 
      int maxlines = 1000; //counts max lines t read/write to the file
      BufferedReader input = null;
      BufferedWriter bw = null;

    try {
      //use buffering, reading one line at a time
      //FileReader always assumes default encoding is OK!
      input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
      try {
          String line = null; //not declared within while loop
        /*
        * readLine is a bit quirky :
        * it returns the content of a line MINUS the newline.
        * it returns null only for the END of the stream.
        * it returns an empty String if two newlines appear in a row.
        */
        //for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        //int count = 0;//initiates the line counter
      while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){

          int count = 0;//initiates the line counter    
          String modified1 = line.substring(2,17);
          String modified2 = line.substring(18,33);
          String modified3 = line.substring(40);        
          String result = "empty";
          result = modified1 + ",," +modified2 + modified3;
          System.out.println (result);          

//        contents.append(line);
//        contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
          //int count = 0;//initiates the line counter
          try {

              contents.append(line);
              contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
          String content = result;

          File file = new File("C:\\temp\\out.txt");//output path

          // if file doesnt exists, then create it
          if (!file.exists()) {
          file.createNewFile();
          }
          for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
              if (count++ % maxlines == 0) {
          FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
          bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);      
              bw.write(content);
          bw.newLine(); 
          }
          bw.close();
          }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //}
        }
      }
      finally {
          input.close();
          bw.close();

      }
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return contents.toString();
  }


/**
  * Change the contents of text file in its entirety, overwriting any
  * existing text.
  *
  * This style of implementation throws all exceptions to the caller.
  *
  * @param aFile is an existing file which can be written to.
  * @throws IllegalArgumentException if param does not comply.
  * @throws FileNotFoundException if the file does not exist.
  * @throws IOException if problem encountered during write.
  */
  static public void setContents(File aFile, String aContents)
                                 throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    if (aFile == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File should not be null.");
    }
    if (!aFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException ("File does not exist: " + aFile);
    }
    if (!aFile.isFile()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Should not be a directory: " + aFile);
    }
    if (!aFile.canWrite()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File cannot be written: " + aFile);
    }

    //use buffering
    Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(aFile, true));
    try {
      //FileWriter always assumes default encoding is OK!
        output.write( aContents );
    }
    finally {
      output.close();
    }

  }

  /** Simple test harness.   */
  public static void main (String... aArguments) throws IOException {
      File testFile = new File("C:\\temp\\in.txt");//input path
      System.out.println("\n" + getContents(testFile));

  }

}
```

I tried to add a counter (count) so it can flush the buffer after a certain amount of lines read. It didn't work.
I know the counter does not work correctly. It doesn't goes to zero After a special number of execution of "while" loop. I added a "for" loop before and after while loop to empty the counter but that didn't work as well.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: start the java application with higher heap size, like `java -Xms:4g myApp`;

Comment: Why don't you open the output file before the loop once?

Answer (score 8):

Try using a [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) instead of a BufferedReader/Writer. When I used a FileInputStream, I could copy a dummy log file that had over 36 MILLION lines and was almost 500MB in size in less than a few seconds.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(from); //Read data from a file
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(to); //Write data to a file
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; //Buffer size, Usually 1024-4096
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
//Close the FileStreams
in.close();
out.close();
```

if you wanted to read the file line by line instead of chunks of bytes, you could use a BufferedReader, but in a different way.

```
// Removed redundant exists()/createNewFile() calls altogether
String line;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String modified1 = line.substring(2,17);
      String modified2 = line.substring(18,33);
      String modified3 = line.substring(40); 
      String result = "empty";
      result = modified1 + ",," +modified2 + modified3;
      System.out.println (result);
      output.append(result + "\n");//Use \r\n for Windows EOL
}
//Close Streams
br.close();
output.close();
```

Like EJP said, don't read an entire file into memory - that's not a smart thing to do at all. Your best bet would be to read each line one-by-one or to read chunks of a file at once - although, for accuracy, reading it line-by-line might be best.

During the `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)`, you should do what would have needed the entire file loaded in there while only 1 line is loaded into the memory. (Such as checking if a line contains **_** or grabbing text from it).

Another thing you could try to do to avoid the OOM exception is  to use multiple Strings.

```
if(contents.length() => (Integer.MAX_VALUE-5000)) { //-5000 to give some headway when checking
    . . .
}
```

Comment: But the OOM error is due to StringBuilder running out of available space.

Comment: @EJP But this is writing to a file. Is that what the OP wanted ?

Comment: The OP's code writes to a file. It also loads the entire file into memory to do so, which isn't necessary.

Comment: OP  probably wants to replicate each line 1000 times to the file which does **not** cause OOM error. The OP probably wants the contents  of the file as well. The above code snippet is just an optimization for writing files and has nothing to do with the OOM error.

Comment: I dont know what he 'probably wants'. Neither do you. What his code *actually does* is copy the the entire file once. All his stuff about maxlines etc is just some probably non-working nonsense that just counts to 1000 and then writes the file. The code in this answer does exactly what the OP's code actually does, without the memory problem.

Comment: @EJP Don't confuse `content` and `contents`, I fell for it too, first.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to read large files into memory. They don't fit. Find a way of processing the file a line at a time, or a record at a time, or a chunk at a time. I can't see any reason here why you can't do that.

Calling `File.exists()` and `File.createNewFile()` immediately before constructing a `FileWriter` around the same `File` is a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to add a counter (count) so it can flush the buffer after a certain amount of lines read. It didn't work. I know the counter does not work correctly. It doesn't goes to zero After a special number of execution of "while" loop. I added a "for" loop before and after while loop to empty the counter but that didn't work as well.
>
> Any Suggestion?

The out of memory error is because your file is so huge that all the contents of that file could not be read into your local variable `contents` in the function `getContents(File aFile)`.

Flushing the buffer has nothing to do with it. Using a [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) instead of a BufferedWriter may help clean up the code a bit. By using PrintWriter, you wouldn't have to do something like :

```
bw.write(content);
bw.newLine();
```

You can change this to :

```
printWriter.println(content);
```

You also forgot to tell us your use-case. In the end, all you do is print all the contents of the file. You could have done this line by line.

Comment: Hard to see how using PrintWriter could have any effect on a memory problem.

Comment: I meant that this was text io. PrintWriter already comes with lots of goodies. Why not use them ?

Comment: For one thing because it swallows exceptions. It's irrelevant to the question being asked. The only part of your answer that is relevant is the final sentence.

Answer (score 0):

To read a huge file in Java you should either user java.util.scanner or apache commons LineIterator.
Both approaches don't load whole file in memory and read file line by line.
Am able to read file of size greater than 1gb using LineIterator.
Please visit this link for more details
http://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file and example.