# Java Out of memory error for reading from and writing to an xlsx

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, xlsx

I need to read several xlsx files looking for data specific to an employee and simultaneously create another xlsx file (if I find data in any of the file)with file name as employee Id appended to the name I found the data in. Eg. there is an employee with emp id 1 and there are severaal xlsx files such as A,B, C... so on; I need to look for data relating to emp id 1 in each file and for the files I get a hit I need to create a file named 1_A.xlsx.

Now although I have built the logic and am using Apache POI APIs for reading and writing, my code is throwing Out Of Memory error after creating just the first  file with the data. And is unable to read the rest of the files.
I have tried using SXSSF instead of XSSF but same OOM happens.

Increasing the heap space is not an option for me.
Please help here...Thanks in advance.

Here is a piece of code :

```
//Reader:


 Row row = null;
   List<Row> listOfRecords = new ArrayList<Row>();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(metaDataFile);
            new InputStreamReader(fis, "ISO-8859-1");
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                row = rowIterator.next();
                if (!isEmptyRow(row)) {
                    listOfRecords.add(row);
                }
            }
            wb.close();
            fis.close();

//Writer
LOGGER.info("in createWorkbook " );
        Workbook empWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(200);
        Sheet empSheet = empWorkbook.createSheet("Itype Sheet For Emp_"
                + personnelNumber);
        int rowNum = listOfRecords.size();
        System.out.println("Creating excel");
        Cell c = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {

            Row record = listOfRecords.get(i);
            Row empRow = empSheet.createRow(i++);
            if (!isEmptyRow(record)) {
                int colNum = record.getLastCellNum() + 1;

                for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
                    Cell newCell = empRow.createCell(j);

                    System.out.println("cellVal:"
                            + String.valueOf(record.getCell(j)));
                    newCell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(record.getCell(j)));

                }
            }
        }
```

The writer method is called from within the reader.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. You'll get a better response if you post some relevant code, including stack trace, and explain what you've tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for hints.

Comment: This topic might possibly help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627508/outofmemoryerror-when-trying-to-read-write-from-a-huge-text-file

Comment: Well - how large are the files, and how much memory is available for the heap space?

Comment: The files are not very large. At an average 5mb.

Comment: I found out that the OOM is arising while trying to read more than one file. Since I am trying to loop through the list of files and read them one by one to extract record.
Please advice how to read through multiple xlsx files without getting this error.@Hulk

Answer (score 0):

Reading of multiple xlsx files is indeed tricky business butI finally solved it.

I had to break down my code several folds to realise that the OOM error was due to the fact that after reading 3 files no more memory was left to process the rest of the files. 
xlsx files are compressed xml files. So when we try to read them using XSSF or SXSSF APIs it loads the entire DOM to the memory thereafter choking it.
I found an excellent solution here :
[https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader]
Hope this will help others who come here facing the same issue.